# Unsure how to treat y in this derivative/log problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Need to find the derivative of $h(y)= \ln(y^2 \cos y)$

Treating it like a normal variable like an x isn't working for me, the way we used y's in earlier problems where you get a y' in there doesn't seem right, so I'm not quite sure here.

Comment: What is the problem?  You've only written a function.

Comment: Oops, sorry, need to find the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematics is invariant under change of notation

*Mathematics is invariant under change of notation*

**Mathematics is invariant under change of notation**

You're doing something wrong if you treat that $y$ as differently than if it was an $x$ or a $\mu$ or small drawing of a house.

$$\frac{d}{dy}h(y)=\frac{2}{y}-\tan(y)$$ holds just as surely as it would if $y$ were $x$.

Answer (score 2):

If $h(y) = \ln(y^2 \cos y)=2 \ln y + \ln(\cos y)$, then
$$
h'(y) = \frac{2}{y} + \frac{-\sin y}{\cos y} = \frac{2}{y} - \tan y
$$

Stella is right.  In this problem, $y$ is an independent variable.  You may have worked other problems where $y$ was dependent on $x$, but this is not the case here.

Comment: Oh ok, I somehow forgot you could separate the inside like that.